# Is it okay to create app data in internal memory

Tags: android

I am developing an app which consists of functionality to take pictures using camera, store it on memory and mail it to the specified users.

I created a folder in the SD card and storing the images there. But some of the new devices like Nexus S are not consisting of any SD card. So, is it okay if we access the internal memory?

If so how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling getExternalFilesDir(DIRECTORY_PIOCTURES) on those devices with no external memory?  Does it return a valid File?  I would expect devices like the Nexus S would still provide a partition for those calls to map onto, even if it's not technically "external".

Comment: I m using the code --- File Dire = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
  "Sample");
  
  Dire.mkdir();   to create new folder. I cant get a method named getExternalFilesDir() in there.

Comment: It's a member of Context:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following code in manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
... >
```

Android will see if external storage is available. if not it will store in internal.

Read this doco on storage of files. http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

in particular application **should and shouldn't** be installed in external storage

Comment: You got my question wrong. I want to create a folder in internal memory if the sd card dont exist. Not to install my whole app on SD

Comment: @Rahul Varma oops.. thanks for clarification. If the sd doesnt exist, then you have no choice other than to create folder in internal memory.

Comment: @Rahul Varma ... just to add.. See section 7.6 of http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-2.3-cdd.pdf ... so that could tell you where you might need to limit your storage usage.